# Changing the screen resolution to the true resolution option not available

Tags: nvidia, xorg, display, resolution

I have recently updated through software update after installing a fresh installation of Ubuntu 12.04 and my screen resolution is completely messed up. The default screen resolutions at the moment are:

```
1600 x 1200 (4:3) -- Using this now and it is quite hard to see the screen considering there is no HDMI, just VGA
1280 x 1024 (5:4)
1024 x 768 (4:3) -- Unusable as when I select it, I get a "Fuzzy" screen
800 x 600 (4:3)
```

I have gone into my `xorg.conf` file and ensured my `vertRefresh` and `horizontal Sync` are all in order and are that specified by my monitors manufacturer. This did not change a thing. I have also tried adding a metamode and mode for the 1366x768 and it still has not worked.

Here is my current xorg.conf file:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 319.17  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-06)  Thu Apr 25 22:28:25 PDT 2013

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 80.0
    VertRefresh     55.0 - 75.0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    # Option "metamodes" "1360x768 +0+0"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
        Modes       "1366x768"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I have also tried using xrandr to set the resolution to 1366 x 768 and it does not work. Any tips on allowing me to get my resolution back to normal? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the right and the latest drivers for your graphic cards?

Check if you can update the driver.

Comment: Yes, I am 100% positive that I do.